# Javascript split conditional

Tags: javascript

Here we go, I have variables :

```
var possible_country = 'United States|Germany|Canada|United Kingdom';
var current_country = 'United States';
```

I want use conditional like this as functions

```
function dummy(c, p){
 var arr = p.split('|');

 /* Code I want */

 if(c === arr[0] || c === arr[1] || c === arr[2] || c === arr[3])
 {
  alert('Voila');
 }
}
```

So I can call dummy function like this

```
dummy(current_country, possible_country);
```

Comment: Can't you just loop through all the countries? (I mean in *arr*) And do that condition you have used but like *if (c==arr[i])*

Comment: I'd probably prefer to have `var isValidCountry = /^(United States|Germany|Canada|United Kingdom)$/` with `if(isValidCountry.test(country))`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want `indexOf`:

```
function dummy(c, p){
 var arr = p.split('|');

 if(~arr.indexOf(p)) { // arr contains p as one of its elements
  alert('Voila');
 }
}
```

Comment: What have I missed?  `~` is the bitwise NOT isn't it?  How does that work?  indexOf isn't even available for arrays until JS 1.6.

Comment: `~-1` will always be false (as -1 is true - in the *all bits are set* sense) everything else (non -1) will be true.

Comment: @Lee, `indexOf()` (which is available in Javascript 1.6 and higher) return `-1` if the element is not found. Since Javascript's bitwise operators use two's complement, `~-1` is `0`, which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski: It happens that `indexOf` returns `-1` if it's not present in the array. `~-1 === 0`, so `~` will return a falsy value if it's not present and a truthy value (some other number than `0`) if it *is* present.

Comment: So it /is/ the bitwise not and not some new syntax then.  Relieved!  Interesting indeed, but sackable round my parts lol.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.indexOf` method for the array:

```
var possible_country = 'United States|Germany|Canada|United Kingdom';
var current_country = 'United States';

possible_country = possible_country.split('|'); //Split by |
alert(possible_country.indexOf(current_country)); //Search for the current_country inside fo possible_country.
```

As a function:

```
function dummy(current, possible) {
    var arr = possible.split('|');
    if (arr.indexOf(current) != -1) {
        alert('voila');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ?

```
function dummy(c, p){
  var arr = p.split('|');
  for (var i in arr)
    if (arr[i]===c)
      alert("OK");
  alert("KO");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the pipe bar at the end

```
var possible_country = 'United States|Germany|Canada|United Kingdom|';
```

you'll just need one line to check:

```
if (possible_country.indexOf(current_country + '|') > -1)
{
    alert('Voila');
}
```